# android making Preferences (CheckBoxPreference) scrollable in XML

Tags: android, android-preferences

Hi, I'm trying to get my preference area to have scrollable text as most of the titles are too long. Is this something thats possible? I have seen posts regarding `TextViews`, and even those need a bit of encouragement to get going...
any help appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with standard `PreferenceActivity` you are most likely use there. Shorten your labels and use `description filed to clarify. Or just create help or manual for your app